# how to add internal frame inside a jdialog

Tags: java

i am using the following code :

```
      JDialog d=new JDialog();
         JInternalFrame i=new JInternalFrame("HI",false,false,false,false);
       i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
     d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     d.setTitle("Wait dialog");
    d.add(i);
     d.pack();
      d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        d.setLocation(300,300);
    d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
   d.setVisible(true);
```

but instead of getting a jdialog of size 100*100, i am getting a small window with the default width and height , why is this happening?
note: I did the same with a JFrame , and i got the result.But i want it on a JDialog.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call pack() on the JDialog after adding all components to it but before displaying it with setVisible(true).

On an unrelated note, it would be a good idea to associate your JDialog with its parent window (possibly a JFrame) via one of the JDialog constructor overloads.

Edit: you don't want to add JInternalFrames directly to a JDialog or other top-level window.  Instead create a JDesktopPane, set its preferredSize, add THAT to the JDialog's contentPane and then add the JInternalFrame to the JDesktopPane.

Edit 2: You'll also need to set the size and position of the internal frame (setBounds will work well for this) and call setVisible(true) on the internal frame.  The Swing tutorial on using internal frames and desktop panes will tell you all about this.

Edit 3:  e.g.,

```
class testDialog {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JDialog d = new JDialog();
      JDesktopPane desktoppane = new JDesktopPane(); // added
      desktoppane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));// added
      JInternalFrame i = new JInternalFrame("HI", false, false, false, false);
      // i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
      i.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);// added
      desktoppane.add(i);
      i.setVisible(true);

      d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      d.setTitle("Wait dialog");
      // d.add(i);
      d.add(desktoppane); // added
      d.pack();
      // d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
      d.setLocation(300, 300);
      d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      d.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: I did that now. But it didnt help.

Comment: Then I suggest that you create and post a very small compilable, runnable demo program, one that shows the problem.  This process is called creating an SSCCE. For more on how to do this best, please check out this link: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Please see my first edit to my answer above.  Sorry for not recommending this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SSCCE:

```
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public class testDialog
  {

public static void main(String []args)
   {
     JDialog d=new JDialog();
    JInternalFrame i=new JInternalFrame("HI",false,false,false,false);
    i.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      d.setTitle("Wait dialog");
   d.add(i);
    d.pack();
   d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    d.setLocation(300,300);
     d.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    d.setVisible(true);
      }
      }
```

Comment: Again, please see the edit to my answer above.  You need to use a JDesktopPane if you want to use JInternalFrames.