# Java prevent JInternalFrame to lose focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jinternalframe

I created a JDesktopPane inside of which there is a menu.
When user clicks on the menu, a JInternalFrame appears.
The JInternalFrame carries data in a JTable and also has some JButtons

[image: JInternalFrame]

What I want to do is to prevent losing focus from JInternalFrame when user tries to click on the menu. The user has to close this JInternalFrame first.

I've read some interesting articles that proposing to use modal JDialog. But as far as I know, they cannot be that customized (or can?).
So, could anyone please help me on this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want to prevent user from clicking on menu and open the same window again, or modify something in another window etc. I am imaging it like Microsoft Word, where user manages only one window at a time. For example when trying to print, he cannot open anything else from menu.

Comment: Well a JDialog can certainly be customized. It depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: can I have a window like that show in the picture with a JDialog?

Comment: JDialog is a `java.awt.Window` and a `javax.swing.RootPaneContainer` so yes you can just put stuff in it. You don't get JInternalFrame behavior but it seems like you don't need it.

Comment: @Radiodef I made a research and I found out that I cannot put multiple JDialogs inside a desktopPane, so I'm afraid I won't have the expected results. Is there anything else you could propably suggest me? I am trying to make an MDI desktop application. I saw this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443056/how-to-add-internal-frame-inside-a-jdialog` but it didn't help me much